# Can't hit redis using DNS name in multi-container pod on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers, dns, redis

Can anyone shed some light on why this might not work? I can access redis just fine using the pod's IP address,

```
$ rdcli -h 10.152.183.65
10.152.183.65:6379>
```

but when I try to use the DNS name, I cannot connect.

```
$ rdcli -h dbbackupd.default.cluster.local
dbbackupd.default.cluster.local:6379> (error) Redis connection to dbbackupd.default.cluster.local:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dbbackupd.default.cluster.local dbbackupd.default.cluster.local:6379
```

Inside the pod that is trying to contact redis, I get the right-looking output when using the host command, so name resolution looks good:

```
$ host dbbackupd.default.svc.cluster.local

dbbackupd.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.152.183.65
```

My theory is that because redis is in a multi-container pod, that dns is not routing it to the container properly. Here is my Service's definition in case that sheds light:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dbbackupd
  labels:
    app: dbbackupd
spec:
  selector:
    app: dbbackupd
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: redis-mq
      protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
    - name: sql-comm
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using two different host names:

```
$ rdcli -h dbbackupd.default.cluster.local
$ host dbbackupd.default.svc.cluster.local
```

The one used with `rdcli` is missing `.svc`.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. I have had a long day, and can't believe I missed something that simple. Anyway, I did confirm that this was the only issue. DNS is working fine, and I can connect to Redis. Thanks for the keen eye.

Comment: I've been there myself more times than I'm willing to admit. :) Glad that's all it was.